# I have no sound on Huawei Matebook D15

Tags: drivers, sound, updates, 22.04, pulseaudio

I installed a Ubuntu 22.04 on my laptop. I started testing it and the sound on my laptop does't work. I tried all possible versions of solving this issue, but I could't find a solution.

Laptop version: Huawei MateBook D15 2021

How do install audio drivers on my laptop?

Comment: I reinstalled pulse audio and alsa mixer. updated kernel version

Comment: after reinstallation, the system still showed a dummy output on the sound

Answer (score 0):

Solution for MateBook D15 BOD-WDI9 under Xubuntu 22.04: install linux-generic and remove all kernels except 5.15.0-76. Good luck !